Calculate a running 7-day total in LibreOffice Calc, where dates may have multiple entries
How do I write a formula that I can copy and paste into a column in a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet so that each cell displays a running 7-day total of the values in a different column. Column A contains dates. Some dates have multiple entries and, therefore, are on multiple rows; for example, Row 3 and Row 3 both have values for April 12. Column E has a value for each entry, in kilograms. Column F will have the running 7-day total of the values in Column E. So for April 18, it will add all the values in Column E from the first April 12 entry through the final April 18 entry. How do I do this?
This is trivial if there is only one row per date. I can't figure out how to do it with some dates having multiple entries, each on a different row.
Here is a picture of the desired result, with the values in F9 and F10 calculated by hand:

I tried using some LLM AIs, and two of them suggested (different) formulas using the SUMIFS function. All variations on the formulas returned various error codes: #NAME? or Err:502 or #VALUE!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The AI couldn't give you the correct formula because you convinced it that column A contained dates. You convinced him of this because you yourself are sure that the number of the form 20240411 is the date April 11, 2024. And this is not true. Try to format the cells in column A as a date and most likely you will receive a #FMT error in each of the cells. You saved two separator characters between year-month-day and got a bad data problem.

Additionally to JohnSun's comment, AIs do not understand programming problems. The best result you can get is on the level of freshmen after their first programming lecture. You need to doubt any detail, and this holds true for any of their answers. However, they provide something to start with, as the freshman you employed.

Thanks for the ideas. Actually, the numbers in column A are dates, in this particular spreadsheet. They are a user-defined format. I can test that by assigning a different date format to a cell, say I1, and inputting the formula A1-1. The result is "04/10/24".

Of course, you can solve the problem using a formula like
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($E$2:E10;
   DATE(LEFT($A$2:A10;4);MID($A$2:A10;5;2);RIGHT($A$2:A10;2));
     "<="&DATE(LEFT(A10;4);MID(A10;5;2);RIGHT(A10;2));
   DATE(LEFT($A$2:A10;4);MID($A$2:A10;5;2);RIGHT($A$2:A10;2))+7;
     ">"&DATE(LEFT(A10;4);MID(A10;5;2);RIGHT(A10;2))));
  "")

or something similar. The formula will take the values in Column A, convert them to date values, and perform further conditional summing with the correct dates.
However, you will make things much easier for both you and Calc if you simply convert the values in column A to dates.
Select column A, use Find&Replace with the parameters
Find (\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)
Replace $1-$2-$3
Current selection only - On
Regular expressions - On.

After this data transformation the formula will be much shorter
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($E$2:E10;$A$2:A10;"<="&A10;$A$2:A10+7;">"&A10))

It should be noted that the last formula will work correctly with old data, "numbers like dates", but the correct results will only be within one month, and at month boundaries you will inevitably get incorrect amounts.

Thanks, John. You put a lot of work into explaining that! The final formula does give the correct answer for the cell you highlighted, yes. But it's not a real running 7-day total; if I change the 4/18 number to 0.6, the answer in column F changes. Also, if I copy and paste it into cells further down the column, the answer doesn't change. How would I modify it so it would look to the date in the first column, find all the values in the second column for the previous seven days, and add them together--and do that for any cell in column F I copy and paste the formula into?

@KalleVT I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. I just changed 0.2 to 0.6 for 2024-04-18 and the =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($E$2:E11;$A$2:A11;"<="&A11;$A$2:A11+7;">"&A11)) formula gave a result of 2.1. I'm afraid that without exchanging sample files and discussing in detail we will not be able to cope with this. Unfortunately, the StackOverflow question-and-answer format does not provide such an opportunity.  Perhaps you should ask this question on some specialized forum?

Sounds like I haven't been clear enough about what I'm looking for. Thanks for your time, @JohnSUN. I'll look into that specialized forum you linked to.
